# Control Cache adding textboxes on auto post back

Tags: c#

When the user selects the amount of textboxes require then that number of textboxes are populated. However, say the user selects 1 then goes back to change the amount to 2; then the amount of textboxes shown is 3. How do I stop it from adding when the page reloads.

```
protected List<Control> ControlCache
{
    get { return (List<Control>)(Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = (Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] as List<Control>) ?? new List<Control>()); }
    set { Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = value; }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (var control in ControlCache)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        }
    }
    else
        ControlCache = null;
}
protected void ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCount.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.MaxLength = 10;

        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        ControlCache.Add(tx);

    }


}
```

Comment: Before adding new textbox, reset everything in ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: @HiteshMistry; give me an example please

Comment: Set ControlCache = null; before for loop in ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: @Hitesh; it is still add to it

Comment: @Hitesh can you assist me please